# Why my Device IP Address is not 192.168.x.x?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I cannot figure out why my phone (Nexus 6P) is the only device on my network that has a IP address which starts differently (65.x.x.x). Can someone explain me why and sometimes it goes back and forth from 192. to 65. I'm an android developer and I need to it stay on the 192. pattern. How do I prevent this from happening. My router is Netgear C7000.

Thank you!

Edit: The IP address isn't an internet IP address because it's the one shown on my router page (Connected devices) next to my device ID, the one next to my Desktop/Laptop are fine. Just this one starts with 65. Not sure why I got down-voted so hard since no one is able to answer my question yet.

Edit2: Added image:
[image]

Comment: thats your IP address on the public internet, provdided by your dataplan, not by your wifi.

Comment: That is the address provided by my router to my device, as I can see that on the router page.

Comment: Hmm, given the new information my certainty that the 65.x IP is an internet facing one has gone down considerably. I suppose the most telling question is whether you have internet connectivity when using this 65.x IP?

Comment: Note that just because the device shows up in your router does not necessarily mean your router provided that IP to it. When your a device attempts to find other IP addresses it broadcasts an ARP request that would be visible to all devices physically connected to the network. Your router could become aware of a device using an IP that is not covered by the router's netmask. If your router *did* provide a 65.x IP to a device while itself configured to a 192.x IP it would represent a malfunctioning router in all cases as they could not talk to each other configured that way.

Comment: I've added an image to explain myself better, and yes I do have internet connection when this happens, even after disabling my phone data.

Comment: Well, we've officially entered the twilight zone and, not being a native, I've no idea which direction is actually up. Your router should be rejecting any attempt to access your gateway from a device configured with a 65.x address. Or any non-192.x address. This is a fundamental component of how TCP/IP protocol works. That means no internet access for that device. So for it to be using a 65.x IP while connected to your router and still have the internet is "non-sense". I mean what's happening is what's happening but I can't even begin to rationalize how it could happen.

Comment: It *is* hypothetically possible to configure these IPs to work together but it would confuse the router and cause it to block access to most of the internet for *all* devices on your network.

Comment: This is extremely annoying to me atm, no other device does this, do you think I should reset my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem, most likely, is that the 65.x.x.x IP you are seeing on your phone is *not* for your phone's WiFi interface. It is most likely the IP for it's LTE (or other cellular data) interface. You can test this by turning off mobile data in your phone's settings. LAN IP ranges are typically 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x. The former being more common in home and small office networks and the latter being more common in large/corporate networks. 65.x.x.x is almost certainly an internet facing IP address.

The reason it likely keeps going back and forth is that it is not maintaining a connection with the WiFi. When the WiFi signal becomes insufficient your phone is switching to mobile data... when the WiFi comes back it tries to use it again. You might also check that your wifi password is stored correctly on the phone (forget the network and re-add it). If you use WPS forget the network and go through the WPS linking process again. Your symptoms sometimes happen when the encryption key used by the device does not match that of the access point.

Comment: Edited my post, although right now I'm getting the correct IP range 192. but soon it will revert back. I'm sure that isn't an internet IP.